# Prove $Pr(A\cup B|C) = Pr(A|C)Pr(B|C)$

Tags: probability

I saw $Pr(A\cup B|C)$ expressed as follows,

$$Pr(A\cup B|C) = Pr(A|C)Pr(B|C)$$

but, I have no idea how to arrive at $Pr(A|C)Pr(B|C)$.

I have that,

$$Pr(A\cup B|C) =  \dfrac{Pr(C[A \cup B])}{Pr(C)}$$

Then by Bayes' Theorem,

$$\dfrac{Pr(C[A \cup B])}{Pr(C)} =  \dfrac{Pr(C|[A \cup B])Pr(A \cup B)}{Pr(C)}$$

However, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: I think you mean $Pr(A\cap B | C) = Pr(A|C)Pr(B|C)$ which is the definition of conditional independence. As $A \subset A\cup B$, it follows that $P(A\cup B | C) \geq P(A|C)$.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't true in general. If it were true, then

$$\mathbf{P}(A \cup B)= \mathbf{P}(A) \mathbf{P}(B)$$ would also be true, in general. But it's not. For instance, suppose we're flipping a coin. Let $A$ denote the event we get a heads, and $B$ denote the event we get a tails. Then the LHS equals $1$, but the RHS equal $1/4$.

Perhaps the book or article you're reading has some further conditions on $A,B$ and $C$?

Comment: Even with further conditions this is basically never true since $P(A\cup B\mid C)\geqslant P(A\mid C)$ and $P(A\cup B\mid C)\geqslant P(B\mid C)$. The OP might mean $P(A\cap B\mid C)$ rather than $P(A\cup B\mid C)$.